# PostgreSQL - Function with local variables - Column reference is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have had a look at other questions that match my subject but in my case the ambiguity, I believe, comes from variable having the same name as a column.

Here is a simplified version of the function I am trying to create:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_id(username TEXT) 
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
  DECLARE
    user_id BIGINT;
    other_param TEXT;
  BEGIN
    SELECT INTO user_id user_id FROM users WHERE users.username = get_user_id.username;

    SELECT INTO other_param users.value FROM users WHERE users.user_id = user_id;

    RETURN user_id;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

The problem is that the `user_id` on the right hand side of the `WHERE` is treated as a reference to the column.

I definitely need `user_id` in a local variable as it will be used in `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations further along the function, but I won't get the it passed as a parameter, only username.

Upon some reading and having previously had some problems with parameters too I realised I can use `get_user_id.username` but it only applies to parameters, not local variables (if I use it with variable the query with fail as there is not FROM-clause for `get_user_id`).

Therefore am I missing something (not so) obvious about using variables in queries inside a function?

--- edit

Apologies I oversimplified the function, of course there's a first query that gets the user_id, and that part is working fine.

Comment: don't you mean `WHERE users.username = username`

Comment: Apologies, I oversimplified my function. I believe it makes more sense now

Comment: i think you can sidestep this problem by picking a different name for your variable, i.e not `user_id`. also, if user_id is functionally dependent on username, you don't _really_ need to store user_id, wherever user_id is used, it can be replaced with username (if necessary via a join to the users table)

Comment: Yes eventually I might have to do that but was also wondering if this is like that by design or I am missing some knowledge about using the variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefix parameters and variables so they are less likely to conflict with column names:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_id (in_username TEXT) 
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
  DECLARE
    v_user_id BIGINT;
  BEGIN
    SELECT u.user_id  INTO v_user_id FROM users u WHERE u.user_id = in_user_id;

    RETURN v_user_id;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Presumably, though, you want to compare user names:

```
    SELECT u.user_id  INTO v_user_id FROM users u WHERE u.username = in_username;
```

Answer (score 8):

Any local variable can be qualified by block label

```
create table foo(a integer);
insert into foo values(10);

do $$
<<mylabel>>
declare
  a int default 5;
  r record;
begin
  select foo.a into r
    from foo
    where foo.a = mylabel.a + 5;
  raise notice '%', r.a;
end;
$$;
NOTICE:  10
DO
```

Usually all possible conflict local variables has prefix - common prefix is `_`.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html

> Sometimes it is impractical to fix all the ambiguous references in a
>   large body of PL/pgSQL code. In such cases you can specify that
>   PL/pgSQL should resolve ambiguous references as the variable

and so on... thus:

```
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_id(username TEXT)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
#variable_conflict use_variable
  DECLARE
    user_id BIGINT;
    other_param TEXT;
  BEGIN
    SELECT INTO user_id users.user_id FROM users WHERE users.username = username;
    RETURN user_id;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

let's check:

```
t=# create table users (user_id int, username text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into users values (1,'a');
INSERT 0 1
t=# select get_user_id('a');
 get_user_id
-------------
           1
(1 row)
```

**Attention - this check has big sense, and if you disable it, you can get some very ugly and very invisible errors. This is pretty dangerous. Don't do it, please.**

Don't use it, unless you see invisible errors or you hold EVERY line under control

Comment: Attention - this check has big sense, and if you disable it, you can got some very ugly and very invisible errors. This is pretty dangerous. Don't do it, please.

Comment: @PavelStehule you think I should remove the answer as potentially dangerous?

Comment: add warning only - is better to know issue than be blind.

Answer (score 0):

It is not missing username filtering? I think you wanted something like:

```
SELECT users.user_id INTO user_id FROM users WHERE users.username = username;
```

Is that way, the value of `users.user_id` will be set in `user_id` variable after a username filtering.